# 60 GB (High volume) TDMS file analysis in Python

Tags: python-3.x, bigdata

I use *npTdms* module to work with National Instruments tdms data frames. I have to deal with huge data sets, for example each of my tdms file corresponds to 60GB. Roughly about ~ 7.8125e+09 double type values. Importing data is only 10% of the job, the rest is number crunching on this imported sets of data.

How do I approach this especially since I have to deal with multiple 60GB files. What's the right way to tackle this?

Things I have tried:

1. Use npTdms and pandas to import it as a data frame - literally takes for ever ~ 15 mins and process single 60GB file, crashes with memory warning when I do it in batch.
2. Use Matlab w/ tdms reader module developed by [Jim Hokanson](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/30023-tdms-reader). Imports single 60GB tdms file within 7.78 seconds. This is far favorable than Python but I know this can be achieved with Python as well.
3. Tried de-fragmenting the tdms after writing to disk to optimize the read-in performance. Didn't make a huge difference with respect to npTdms and pandas method. Haven't tried it in matlab.

Comment: We expect you to provide things that you have tried, or at least something more than 'how do I do this'.

Comment: @BramVanroy I have updated the post